# Pass env variables to gradle.properties

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I have a property set like this:

```
url=localhost:3206
```

Is there a way to specifiy this like below instead:

```
url=${hostname}:3206
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think gradle.properties supports interpolation. However, I would suggest an alternative means to accomplishing this:

Have the following in your gradle.properties:

```
hostname=localhost
port=3206
```

Somewhere in your build.gradle, do the following:

```
beforeEvaluate {
  ext.url = "$hostname:$port"
}
```

To configure the hostname or port, you have [several options](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html). I prefer using project environmental variables like:

```
ORG_GRADLE_PROJECT_hostname=0.0.0.0
ORG_GRADLE_PROJECT_port=4321
```

Now when you run your project, gradle will pick up the environmental variables and replace the ones in gradle.properties with these.