# How to pass nexus credentials in a gradle task to download the artifacts

Tags: gradle

I am trying to download the artifact from nexus to my local directory using gradle task.I have to pass username/password in my gradle task to downlaod the artifact.Below is my Gradle Task

```
task downloadFile(type: MyDownload) {
  sourceUrl = 'http://localhost:8081/xxx/xxx/xxx'
  target = new File('E:/bookstore/', 'build.zip')
}
```

```java
class MyDownload extends DefaultTask {
  @Input
  String sourceUrl

  @OutputFile
  File target

  @TaskAction
  void download() {
    ant.get(src: sourceUrl, dest: target)
  }
}
```

I am able to access with this task when i remove authorization in nexus but i need to enable authorization in nexus and pass the credentials through Gradle task

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do this, but my favourite is doing it through special environment variables which can be read as project properties.

```sh
ORG_GRADLE_PROJECT_nexus_user=foo
ORG_GRADLE_PROJECT_nexus_password=bar
```

Inside your task, just look for the project properties `nexus_user` and `nexus_password`:

```java
@TaskAction
void download() {
    def user = project.findProperty('nexus_user') ?: ''
    def pass = project.findProperty('nexus_password') ?: ''
    ...
}
```

See also [Pass env variables to gradle.properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61577070/pass-env-variables-to-gradle-properties/61585963#61585963)