# How to debug SpringBoot using Gradle commandline parameter, without suspending server?

Tags: java, spring-boot, debugging, gradle, command-line

I'd like to start my SpringBoot application, on debug mode, using Gradle (to use on my machine the same command that is used on production)

To start my server I use

```
$ gradle bootRun
```

And I know that I can add a parameter to start on debug mode

```
$ gradle bootRun --debug-jvm
```

The problem is that the above command makes the server suspends (the server is not started until I connect the debugger)

I can have the desired behavior by adding the following code to the build.gradle, however, I'd like to use a command-line parameter, to avoid to commit the build.gradle by mistake.

```
bootRun {
   jvmArgs(['-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005'])
}
```

Note: If I add the following parameters I'll be debuging the gradle daemon (or another gradle thing), not my app, so it's not a valid solution also:

```
gradle bootRun -Dorg.gradle.jvmargs="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005"
```

Note 2: the following code doesn't work - the server starts on non-debug mode

```
gradle bootRun -Dagentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005
```

Related: [how to debug spring application with gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39490624/how-to-debug-spring-application-with-gradle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are basically asking how to pass variables to your project.

Gradle has [many](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html) ways of doing this. I prefer the [project properties](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:project_properties) approach.

Create an environmental variable like:

```
ORG_GRADLE_PROJECT_debug_jvm=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005
```

#### gradle.build

```
bootRun {
   jvmArgs project.findProperty('debug_jvm') ?: ''
}
```

See also: [Pass env variables to gradle.properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61577070/pass-env-variables-to-gradle-properties)

Comment: Thanks! Solved, with: `bootRun {  if (project.hasProperty('debug')) { jvmArgs(['-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005']) } }`. Then I just need to add -Pdebug on commandline